# Nginx не находит CSS

Tags: django, nginx

Не могу понять, почему предыдущий проект работал на этих настройках, а этот — нет. Проект запущен на Django.

Настройки nginx:

```
location /static/ {
    access_log off;
        alias /root/newsite/ksyshev/project/static/;
    }
```

Путь на сервере, где лежит `/root/newsite/ksyshev/project/static`

Логи nginx:

```
2023/04/24 13:30:06 [error] 854595#854595: *5 "/root/newsite/ksyshev/project/static/styles_bar.css/index.html" is not found (20: Not a directory), client: 95.161.145.214, server: ci41159.tw1.ru, request: "GET /static/styles_bar.css/ HTTP/1.1", host: "ci41159.tw1.ru", referrer: "https://ci41159.tw1.ru/video/"
2023/04/24 13:30:06 [error] 854595#854595: *6 "/root/newsite/ksyshev/project/static/js/scripts.js/index.html" is not found (20: Not a directory), client: 95.161.145.214, server: ci41159.tw1.ru, request: "GET /static/js/scripts.js/ HTTP/1.1", host: "ci41159.tw1.ru", referrer: "https://ci41159.tw1.ru/video/"
2023/04/24 13:30:14 [error] 854595#854595: *6 "/root/newsite/ksyshev/project/static/js/scripts.js/index.html" is not found (20: Not a directory), client: 95.161.145.214, server: ci41159.tw1.ru, request: "GET /static/js/scripts.js/ HTTP/1.1", host: "ci41159.tw1.ru", referrer: "https://ci41159.tw1.ru/photo/"
2023/04/24 13:30:14 [error] 854595#854595: *5 "/root/newsite/ksyshev/project/static/styles_bar.css/index.html" is not found (20: Not a directory), client: 95.161.145.214, server: ci41159.tw1.ru, request: "GET /static/styles_bar.css/ HTTP/1.1", host: "ci41159.tw1.ru", referrer: "https://ci41159.tw1.ru/photo/"
2023/04/24 13:30:14 [error] 854595#854595: *4 open() "/root/newsite/ksyshev/project/static/images/IMG_2979.JPG" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 95.161.145.214, server: ci41159.tw1.ru, request: "GET /static/images/IMG_2979.JPG HTTP/1.1", host: "ci41159.tw1.ru", referrer: "https://ci41159.tw1.ru/photo/"
2023/04/24 14:06:49 [error] 855609#855609: *1 "/root/newsite/ksyshev/project/static/styles_bar.css/index.html" is not found (20: Not a directory), client: 95.161.145.214, server: ci41159.tw1.ru, request: "GET /static/styles_bar.css/ HTTP/1.1", host: "ci41159.tw1.ru", referrer: "https://ci41159.tw1.ru/photo/"
2023/04/24 14:06:50 [error] 855609#855609: *1 "/root/newsite/ksyshev/project/static/js/scripts.js/index.html" is not found (20: Not a directory), client: 95.161.145.214, server: ci41159.tw1.ru, request: "GET /static/js/scripts.js/ HTTP/1.1", host: "ci41159.tw1.ru", referrer: "https://ci41159.tw1.ru/photo/"
2023/04/24 14:06:50 [error] 855609#855609: *1 open() "/root/newsite/ksyshev/project/static/images/IMG_2979.JPG" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 95.161.145.214, server: ci41159.tw1.ru, request: "GET /static/images/IMG_2979.JPG HTTP/1.1", host: "ci41159.tw1.ru", referrer: "https://ci41159.tw1.ru/photo/"
2023/04/24 14:06:54 [error] 855609#855609: *2 "/root/newsite/ksyshev/project/static/styles_bar.css/index.html" is not found (20: Not a directory), client: 95.161.145.214, server: ci41159.tw1.ru, request: "GET /static/styles_bar.css/ HTTP/1.1", host: "ci41159.tw1.ru", referrer: "https://ci41159.tw1.ru/"
2023/04/24 14:06:54 [error] 855609#855609: *1 "/root/newsite/ksyshev/project/static/js/scripts.js/index.html" is not found (20: Not a directory), client: 95.161.145.214, server: ci41159.tw1.ru, request: "GET /static/js/scripts.js/ HTTP/1.1", host: "ci41159.tw1.ru", referrer: "https://ci41159.tw1.ru/"
```

Comment: У вас в html-коде неправильные ссылки, зачем-то слэши в конце

Comment: Сам сайт заработал спасибо, но админка Django грузится без стилей, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А вы collectstatic не забыли сделать?

Comment: ‍♂️ спасибо)!

Comment: решил проблему? такая же ситуация